# How to draw in canvas in GWT

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, gwt, canvas

I have this simple jQuery code for drawing a triangle in a 40 by 40 canvas element:

```
var context1 = $("#arrow_left").get(0).getContext('2d');
context1.beginPath();
context1.moveTo(25,0);
context1.lineTo(0,20);
context1.lineTo(25,40);
context1.lineTo(25,0);
context1.fill();
context1.closePath();
```

Now how do I do the same thing in GWT? There is a tutorial at http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/wiki/GWTCanvas, but the page itself says that that is deprecated and suggests using http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/canvas/client/Canvas.html. However the latter has no documentation on drawing. Can anyone tell me how to do it in GWT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the canvas you can get the [Context2d](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/canvas/dom/client/Context2d.html) object, which has the same methods as your context1 variable.

Just call the same methods ;-)

Sample Code:

```
Canvas canvas = Canvas.createIfSupported();
Context2d context1 = canvas.getContext2d();
context1.beginPath();
context1.moveTo(25,0);
context1.lineTo(0,20);
context1.lineTo(25,40);
context1.lineTo(25,0);
context1.fill();
context1.closePath();
```

Comment: Oh. So basically not much different from how I did with JS, right?

Comment: Yeah, that seriously sucks! :P

Comment: One issue, I have a defined canvas element with id, say `foo`. How do I draw to it? Where do I mention the `id` of the canvas element?

Comment: You shouldn't mix jQuery style of programming with GWT (unless you have to). GWT follows the Java way: objects everywhere, type safety, anonymous classes and so on. If you don't like the style, GWT isn't for you. That said, to get an Element by id, use `Element el = DOM.getElementById("foo");`, and then `canvas.setElement(el);`.

Comment: This `canvas.setElement(el)` should follow `Canvas canvas = Canvas.createIfSupported();`?

Comment: By the way, you are right, I don't like GWT at all..Can't help it, I am stuck! :(

Answer (score 3):

I think this following link will help you. It has source code also.
http://gwtcanvasdemo.appspot.com/

Before that download jwt-incubator http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/gwt-incubator/gwt-incubator.jar.zip and add inherited module in .gwt.xml file.Then add this jar to library.